# Gitlab-runner failed to remove permission denied

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline with Gitlab. I've installed gitlab-runner on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.04 droplet and gave permissions in `/etc/sudoers` to the gitlab-runner as:

```
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL:ALL)ALL
```

The first commit to the associated repository correctly build the docker-compose (the app itself is Django+postgres), but following commits are not able to clean previous builds and fail:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.8.0 (1b659122)
on ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-fra1-01 52WypZsE
Using Shell executor...
00:00
Running on ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-fra1-01...
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
00:01
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/52WypZsE/0/lorePieri/djangocicd/.git/
 From https://gitlab.com/lorePieri/djangocicd
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/120533457 -> refs/pipelines/120533457
    0072002..bd28ba4  develop                  -> origin/develop
 Checking out bd28ba46 as develop...
 warning: failed to remove app/staticfiles/admin/img/selector-icons.svg: Permission denied
 warning: failed to remove app/staticfiles/admin/img/search.svg: Permission denied
 warning: failed to remove app/staticfiles/admin/img/icon-alert.svg: Permission denied
 warning: failed to remove app/staticfiles/admin/img/tooltag-arrowright.svg: Permission denied
 warning: failed to remove app/staticfiles/admin/img/icon-unknown-alt.svg: Permission denied
```

This is the relevant portion of the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - deploy_staging
  - deploy_production

step-test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - export DYNAMIC_ENV_VAR=DEVELOP
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - develop
  script:
    - echo running tests in $DYNAMIC_ENV_VAR
    - sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
    - sudo pip install docker-compose
    - sudo docker image prune -f
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
    - echo do tests now
    - sudo docker-compose exec -T web python3 -m coverage run --source='.' manage.py test

...
```

What I've tried:

```
usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out ?

Comment: @silkAdmin  I have added a new answer. I have had the same problem. would you please take a look at it and give upvote if it is useful?

Answer (score 15):

The best solution for me was adding

```
pre_clone_script = "sudo chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner ."
```

into `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`
Even if you won't have permissions after a previous job it'll set correct permissions before cleaning up the workdir and cloning the repo.

Comment: Add it in the [[runners]] section for your runner.

Comment: How do you pass sudo password?

Comment: @OrkhanM. looks like it was **sudoers** file

Comment: @VladMazurkov true.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting a GIT_STRATEGY to none in the afflicted job.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: First, I would create a job that wipes all preexisting build data with `sudo rm -rf * && sudo rm -rf .git*`, with a GIT_STRATEGY of none. Then, the following job which is the one to clone your project should have a GIT_STRATEGY set to clone. That way, when you test, you always start with a totally empty folder when you clone, meaning you don't get denied permissions trying to overwrite stuff. For more info on how to declare those in your YML: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem. Therefore I will explain how it was resolved in details.

Try finding your `config.toml` file and run the `gitlab-runner` command with root privileges, since *permission denied* is a very common UNIX-based operating systems error.

After finding the location of `config.toml` pass it:

```
sudo gitlab-runner run --config <absolute_location_of_config_toml>
```

**P.S.** You can find all `config.toml` file easily using `locate config.toml` command. Make sure you have already installed by executing `sudo apt-get install mlocate`

1. After facing to `permission denied` error, I have tried using `sudo gitlab-runner run` instead of `gitlab-runner`, but it has its own problem:

   ```
   ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such 
   file or directory  builds=0
   ```

   while executing gitlab-runner without root permissions doesn't have any config file problem.
2. Try implementing the ways and solutions as @Grumbanks and @vlad-Mazurkov mentioned. But they didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It MAY be because you write a file in cloned out codebase. What I do is simply create another directory outside of gitlab-runner directory:

```
WORKSPACE_DIR="/home/abcd_USER/a/b"
rm -rf $WORKSPACE_DIR
mkdir -p $WORKSPACE_DIR
cd $WORKSPACE_DIR
ls -la
git clone ..................
AND DO whatever
```

I never faced the issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue while running a robotframework docker job, that should write its output back the runner's filesystem. The problem was that they were owned by `root` and thus couldn't be updated by subsequent processes anymore.

The answer is given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627027/files-created-by-docker-container-are-owned-by-root)

Just add `-u ${UID}` to your `docker/docker-compose run` command and the output files are owned by the current user running the docker job.

Answer (score 0):

gitlab-runner error:

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 14.10.1 (f761588f)
  on XXX Core Edition i8pfD5N9
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on devserver...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx/.git/
Checking out 897db0d2 as dev...
warning: failed to remove xxx/bin/Release/net6.0/xxx.dll: Permission denied
```

It is obvious that there is a permission issue. I checked the permissions of `xxx/bin`:

```bash
ls -l /home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx/bin
```

The result is:

```bash
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 15 09:12 Release
```

Normally, the user here should be `gitlab-runner`, not `root`.

I realized that this might be caused by my use of `sudo`, so I removed all the `sudo` in the script.

Then I changed the user of runner `i8pfD5N9` to `root` to ensure the highest user privileges. Later I realized that this step might not be necessary.

```bash
nano /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

```bash
[[runners]]
  name = "xxx"
  url = "http://192.168.0.2/"
  token = "i8pfD5N9SNp-qQ8oRUN4"
  executor = "shell"
  user = "root"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

After making the modifications, another error occurred:

```bash
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx/.git/
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I followed the prompt and executed:

```bash
git config --global --add safe.directory /home/gitlab-runner/builds/i8pfD5N9/0/xxx/xxx
```

Finally, the problem was resolved!